# What is this dot on my Firefox 4 file menu?

Tags: firefox

Since I have upgraded to Firefox 4, there is a tiny dot on the File part of the menu. Clicking on it does nothing, it blocks the menu function over the area it covers.

Please tell me what this is supposed to be or things I can try to find out. I haven't noticed this dot in any other application.

The dot is visible on the picture to the left of the 'F' in "File":

[image: wierd dot on firefox menu]

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Unity?

Could you provide a larger screenshot that includes the whole left of the screen?

It might be the small "arrow" bullet that appears and points to the application's launcher icon, or an artefact of it.

Comment: I didn't notice it, but it's gone by now. I am not using unity. This small dot did move with the FF window and did not change whatever I was doing. So I think it doesn't depend on anything to the left of the window.